# How to read exchange email with unattended console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, console-application, exchangewebservices

I have been trying to implement a solution for this for days. It's my first experiment with Microsoft Graph. I had our network admin register the app and went through the quick start  code in [console-app-quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/console-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-dotnet-core).
I looked at [active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) and [active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2).

```
var App = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
  .Create("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
  .WithTenantId("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
  .Build();
```

The `PublicClientApplication` has the `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` function. This sounds good because we can launch the console app as whatever user we want to use with a scheduled task. But it errors out with WS-Trust endpoint not found. Where's WS-Trust endpoint defined?
The sample also includes the line `var accounts = await App.GetAccountsAsync()` but that always returns zero accounts. Some responses to searches for this say that we have to use the global tenant admin. The company doesn't like that idea at all. How can that be safe? Do we create a new user as an admin tenant just for that?

The other option is this

```
var App = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
  .WithClientSecret("aeiou~XXXXXXXXXXX")
  .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"))
  .Build();
```

The `ConfidentialClientApplication` doesn't have the integrated windows auth version. I can get connected and get MailFolders and Messages and process those, but it seems to work only when we use `App.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)` and API permissions that allow the app to read everyone's email. Security doesn't like that much either.
I also looked at [impersonation-and-ews-in-exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/impersonation-and-ews-in-exchange). I read in some places that ExchangeWebService is deprecated and use MS Graph instead. Is the MS Graph API permissions in the EWS category mean that it's going to be around?

Can anyone out there show me the right combination of pieces needed to do this? (api permissions, client application type, scopes, authority, etc). It needs to be unattended (launched by scheduled task), needs to have permissions to read only one email box, and save the attachments.

(sorry so long)
Thanks, Mike

Comment: @TinyWang As a matter of fact I do. I had to wait for the Azure admin to get some free time but we tried the solution of limiting the app to the email group and that worked. I can read what I need but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WS-Trust endpoint not found

The WS-Trust endpoint is your ADFS endpoint, if you have ADFS 2019 then MSAL does support that using WithAdfsAuthority see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications.md

There are some other restriction around using WIA that are listed at the top of https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication-in-MSAL-2.x . If the constraints don't affect you it should work okay.

With the Client Credentials flow which is what your using above you can restrict the scope of the mailboxes it can access see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

I would stick with the Graph rather then EWS as the later is being phased out and requires more permissions as its a legacy API.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you shared in the question is an asp.net core console app. Since you want to have a console app and use it to read exchange mails.
Therefore, what we can confirm is that: We need to use MS Graph API to read the exchange mails. Graph API required an Azure AD application with correct API permissions to generate Access token to call the API. [API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) have 2 types, `Delegated` for Web app because it required users to sign in to obtain the token, `Application` for daemon app like console application which don't require an user-sign-in.

Since you are using the asp.net core console application, you can only using `Application` API permission. Using `Application` permission means the console app has the permission to query messages of any email address in your tenant. You can't control the Graph API itself to query some specific users only. But you can write your own business logic to set authorization.

[image]

Then we can make the console application authorized to access the API, we can generate an Access token and use it in the HTTP request header to call the API, we can also use the Graph SDK. Using SDK will help to troubleshoot when met error.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_id";
var clientId = "Azure_AD_app_id";
var clientSecret = "Azure_AD_client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var messages = await graphClient.Users["{email_address/user_account/user_id}"].Messages.Request().Select("sender,subject").GetAsync();
```